# The system always requires reboot

Tags: upgrade, reboot

The system always requires reboot. Writes: "Restart your computer to complete the update." After rebooting the message again.
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this sequence in your `terminal` :

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and next:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

if you want to upgrade your distribution run this:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then:

```
sudo reboot
```

Enjoy your Ubuntu! :)